# Scrape the text below a header inside a list item into a column with BeautifulSoup and pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape and store some items using BeautifulSoup and pandas. The code below only partially works. As you can see it scrapes 'Engine426/425 HP' whereas I only want the string '426/425 HP' to be stored in the 'engine' column. I would like to scrape all 4 h5 strings in the HTML below (Please refer to the desired output below). I hope someone can help me out, thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

main_url = "https://www.example.com/"

def getAndParseURL(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    return(soup)

soup = getAndParseURL(main_url)

engine = []

engine.append(soup.find("ul", class_ = re.compile('list-inline lot-breakdown-list')).li.text)

scraped_data = pd.DataFrame({'engine': engine})

scraped_data.head()

              engine
0   Engine426/425 HP
```

HTML

```
<div class="lot-breakdown">
    <ul class="list-inline lot-breakdown-list">
        <li>
            <h5>Engine</h5>426/425 HP</li>
        <li>
            <h5>Trans</h5>Automatic</li>
        <li>
            <h5>Color</h5>Alpine White</li>
        <li>
            <h5>Interior</h5>Black</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Desired output

```
scraped_data[['engine', 'trans', 'color', 'interior']] = pd.DataFrame([['426/425 HP', 'Automatic', 'Alpine White', 'Black']], index=scraped_data.index)
scraped_data

              engine        trans          color  interior
0         426/425 HP    Automatic   Alpine White     Black
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that in too many ways :

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup , NavigableString
    import requests

    main_url = "https://www.example.com/"

    def getAndParseURL(url):
        result = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
        return(soup)

    soup = getAndParseURL(main_url)
    #ul   = soup.select('ul[class="list-inline lot-breakdown-list"] li')
    #for li in ul :
         #x = li.find(text=True, recursive=False) # Will give you the text of the li skipping the text of child tag
         #y = ' '.join([t for t in li.contents if type(t)== NavigableString]) # contents [<h5>Engine</h5>, '426/425 HP'] the text you want has a type of NavigableString and That's what we are returning .
    ul = soup.select('ul[class="list-inline lot-breakdown-list"] li', recursive=True)
    lis_e = []
    for li in ul:
        lis = []
        lis.append(li.contents[1])
        lis_e.extend(lis)

    engine.append(lis_e[0])
    trans.append(lis_e[1])
    color.append(lis_e[2])
    interior.append(lis_e[3])

    scraped_data = pd.DataFrame({'engine': engine, 'transmission': trans, 'color': color, 'interior': interior})
    scraped_data
```

Comment: Thanks man! I haven't figured out yet how to get my desired output. I need to append each 'y' to the desired column. If I append it to a list I get 4 separate lists in one object. If I can get it to store each header text in one list I can easily extract it. Do you know how to do this? Thanks again

`ul = soup.select('ul[class="list-inline lot-breakdown-list"] li')
for li in ul:
    lis = []
    y = ' '.join([t for t in li.contents if type(t)== NavigableString])
    lis.append(y)
    print(lis)`

Comment: Ok figured it out, had to extend the list. I've edited your code which gets my desired result.